# How to set the bottom navigation bar option same color?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

In my bottom navigation bar, I have 3 options. 
In bottom navigation bar default [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR2jl.png), one option is selected color another two is in another color. I [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYr2O.png)  all the 3 option same color. What can I do?

**xml code:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"/>
```

**Menu xml(my_navigation_items):**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
     android:title="@string/menu_share"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_share" />
   <item android:id="@+id/action_fav"
     android:title="@string/menu_fav"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_unfav" />
   <item
     android:id="@+id/action_delete"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
     android:title="@string/menu_delete" />
</menu>
```

**java code:**

```
  bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_share:

                        case R.id.action_fav:

                        case R.id.action_delete:

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: post some code to better help

Comment: You can paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick might help for you.

**app:itemIconTint** is property in BottomNavigationView.

Add **bottom_navigation_color_selector.xml** in your **BottomNavigationView**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_sheet_menu" />
```

**bottom_navigation_color_selector.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

Comment: My pleasure, happy to help u

Answer (score 0):

Look the material design documentation of bottom navigation bar component

https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs

Try using  `android:state_enabled` for the selector item attributes.

Comment: please tell brief